# Having trouble with troubleshooting what's going wrong in testflight with my ionic react firebase app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, ionic-framework, testflight

I am trying to test my react/ionic/firebase app on testflight but its having errors that do not come up on my simulator.

I believe the problem is with my capacitor.config.json file:

```
{
  "appId": "com.traineraid.KaseyKaufmann",
  "appName": "TrainerAid",
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "webDir": "build",
  "plugins": {
    "SplashScreen": {
      "launchShowDuration": 0
    }
  },
  "cordova": {},
  "server": {
    "url": "http://localhost:8100",
    "cleartext": true
  }
}
```

I have seen the problem would be the server url since its localhost. when i have it there, it gets to the login screen but after i login, the screen goes blank. I can have deduced that information is being requested properly from firebase to log in. It just doesnt go to the next page after the log in.

If I dont have the localhost in the config above, it will open the splash screen and then the screen will go blank and nothing will happen.

I'm super lost on what I can do to even figure this out so any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: remove the "server" part from your `capacitor.config.json` it is supposed to be used only for live reloading and not in the actual app..
Why don't you test the app on an actual device without pushing it to testflight? Installing the app from xcode on your ios device..

Comment: I’ll test it out but I’ve been having a bug from Xcode itself about building on a real device. But would you know why I’m able to do more on a local host server in this scenario? I find it very odd

Comment: Run this command `ionic build && ionic cap sync ios`, followed by deploying your app to testflight.. If this still persists, you should first try fixing the xcode build issue on real device.. and then you will be able to debug your app to see any relevant console errors..

Comment: My problem in running on a real device is this error ```dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Capacitor.framework/Capacitor
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2CDFDDCD-9F27-42BF-AA2B-ABF7FD839866/App.app/App
  Reason: no suitable image found.``` It seems to be a problem with a lot of people caused by an internal error in xcode. Ive been stuck on it for a while

Comment: Well I am sure there must be solution for that error too.. I test my apps on device.. Try searching for existing solutions here or at https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues . Raise a separate question here if nothing works.. did you try running the command mentioned above?

Comment: Yes but it still had the same problem. The most common reason I’ve seen for the previous comment seems to be that a free developer account doesn’t work and the solution just means to get a paid one. But I already have that. I’ve gone through a dozen different suggestions I’ve seen online but nothing has worked

Comment: You should raise a separate query for it in capacitor teams github issues.. I personally test capacitor apps on real devices by building through xcode.. so it must be some configuration issue..

Answer (score 1):

if you run the proper ionic command to build to device, it will clean up the configuration file for you instead of manually editing it yourself.

```
ionic build
ionic cap run ios
```